# How is possible get only the device to capture or playback using pjsua2

Tags: c++, pjsua2

I trying get the devices from pjsua2 , I got it get all devices, but do not got split in capture device and playback device.

```
void AudioController::load(){
    Endpoint ep;
    ep.libCreate();
    // Initialize endpoint
    EpConfig ep_cfg;
    ep.libInit( ep_cfg );
    AudDevManager &manager  =  ep.audDevManager();
    manager.refreshDevs();
    this->input.clear();
    const AudioDevInfoVector &list = manager.enumDev();
    for(unsigned int i = 0;list.size() != i;i++){
        AudioDevInfo * info = list[i];
        GtAudioDevice * a = new GtAudioDevice();
        a->name = info->name.c_str();
        a->deviceId = i;
        qDebug() << info->name.c_str();
        qDebug() << info->driver.c_str();
         qDebug() << info->caps;
        this->input.append(a);
    }
    ep.libDestroy();
}
```

This is my output:

```
Wave mapper
WMME
23
Microfone (Dispositivo de High 
WMME
3
Alto-falantes (Dispositivo de H
WMME
21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the fields `inputCount` and `outputCount` inside `AudioDevInfo`.

According the documentation:

> unsigned **inputCount**
>
> Maximum number of input channels supported by this device.  If the
>   value is zero, the device does not support input operation (i.e. **it is
>   a playback only device**).

And

> unsigned **outputCount**
>
> Maximum number of output channels supported by this device.  If the
>   value is zero, the device does not support output operation (i.e. **it
>   is an input only device**).

So you could do something like this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0;list.size() != i;i++){
    AudioDevInfo * info = list[i];
    GtAudioDevice * a = new GtAudioDevice();
    a->name = info->name.c_str();
    a->deviceId = i;
    if (info->inputCount > 0) {
        a->captureDevice = true;
    }
    if (info->outputCount > 0) {
        a->playbackDevice = true;
    }
    this->input.append(a);
}
```

Reference: http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpj_1_1AudioDevInfo.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can check the field `caps` (capabilities). Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    AudioDevInfo * info = list[i];
    if ((info.caps & (int)pjmedia_aud_dev_cap.PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_LATENCY) != 0)
    {
        // Playback devices come here
    }
    if ((info.caps & (int)pjmedia_aud_dev_cap.PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_LATENCY) != 0)
    {
        // Capture devices come here
    }
}
```

`caps` is combined from these possible values:

```
enum pjmedia_aud_dev_cap {
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_EXT_FORMAT = 1,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_LATENCY = 2,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_LATENCY = 4,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_VOLUME_SETTING = 8,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_VOLUME_SETTING = 16,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_SIGNAL_METER = 32,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_SIGNAL_METER = 64,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_ROUTE = 128,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_SOURCE = 128,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_ROUTE = 256,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_EC = 512,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_EC_TAIL = 1024,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_VAD = 2048,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_CNG = 4096,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_PLC = 8192,
  PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_MAX = 16384
}
```